# Rails: How can I share a common object across different actions (that is unique to each user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

I am building a rails3 application and I'm using the excellent ['gmail' gem](https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail) to do some work with gmail. Each user enters his/her username and password and the gem creates a connection to gmail that can be used to fetch emails or send new emails.

How can I share this connection variable across actions in the same controller without having to create a new connection every time?

ex. user logs in with his details:

```
@gmail = Gmail.connect(email, pass)
```

then user clicks on a link that calls a different action, for example to read new emails:

```
@newemails = @gmail.inbox.count(:unread)
```

well the problem is that I cannot reuse this @gmail connection object in the 'unread' action as it is nil. I cannot store this in a session variable or in the database as it is not a string. And I cannot store this in a @@class_variable as the connection variable is not global across all sessions - each user must have its own connection obviously.

What is the best way to share this object across different actions?

Many thanks for your help,
Alex

Comment: What's wrong in connecting each time?

Comment: You can Marshal your object. session(:gmail) = Marshal.dump(@gmail). But a new connection might be better.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I was really trying to see if there is some kind of 'best practice' for sharing a connection variable, for ex. what do you do when you fetch some data through an API, do you establish a connection each time or do you reuse a recent connection across actions? Obviously establishing a new connection is more process intensive. 
I ended up establishing a new connection with each action, saving the username & pass in session variables which again is not very elegant security-wise.
Thank you very much for your replies though!